# How an activity go back to a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

There is an `Activity` A including two `fragment` B and C.

And there are also two `Activities` D and E.

Now I click a button in C to go D, and click another button in D to go E.
C -> D -> E.

There is no problem.

Now I'm in `Activity` E, And I want to go back to D then go back to C.

E -> D -> C. There is something wrong.

The order is E->D->E->D...when I click the back button.

All `Activities` I used call `finish()`.

**How can I get the right order E -> D -> C?**

Comment: Please provide ALL relevant code on how you move from your fragments and activities.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use finish() if you want to go back to that activity. If you look at the activity lifecycle, finish() calls the onDestroy(). Check here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html
With regards to going back to the fragment, look at the documentation and look for addToBackstack() method. This documentation will help with proper navigation: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html
Please let me know if you battling with anything

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will read the information that you gave to me. And if there are some problems I will let you know.